# not getting paypal transaction id in return url while paying to buyers account

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

when i am paying to pay-pal business account, I got transaction-id(tx) & payment status(st) in return URL. but when i am paying to buyers/personal account then I did not get anything in return URL.

//paypal.php ($ll_pp_email will be buyers email id)

```
$this_script = BASE_URL.'admin/ukorder/paypal';
$this->paypal_class->add_field('business', $ll_pp_email);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('cmd', '_xclick');
$this->paypal_class->add_field('upload', '1');
$this->paypal_class->add_field('amount', $landlord_amount);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('item_name', this->input->post('prop_title'));
$this->paypal_class->add_field('return', $this_script.'/success');
$this->paypal_class->add_field('cancel_return', $this_script.'/cancel');
$this->paypal_class->add_field('notify_url', $this_script.'/ipn');
$this->paypal_class->add_field('currency_code', 'GBP');
$this->paypal_class->add_field('invoice', $invoice);
$this->paypal_class->add_field('email', ADMIN_EMAIL_ADD);
$this->paypal_class->submit_paypal_post($sandbox);
```

//on success

```
if(!empty($_GET['st']) && !empty($_GET['tx']))  
{
    $payment_status = $_GET['st'];
    $transaction_id = $_GET['tx'];

    if($payment_status=='Completed')
    {
       //further coding
    }
}
```

But when I am paying from business to personal/buyer account, I didn't get paypal parameters in return url.

Comment: you should check with the PayPal API. May be they are returning different values for different type of accounts

Comment: I've provided code snippet with it also, please look into this